# How to add resx file in visual studio express 2012?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

[image: screenchot:AddNewItem]  I'm trying to localize my WPF project, but it seems that there is no option to add a *.resx* file?

There is a resource file in project's directory which is for all resources(strings, images, audio files etc). But from my understanding, you can add strings for only one language.

Comment: Search installed templates for 'Resource file'. If it is not present, search in the `online` section of this dialog.

Comment: Already did that. It's not on installed templates and online I get no templates at all. For every category "No items available for Visual c#)

Comment: May be try closing all your Visual Studio instances and run `devenv /installvstemplates` command. This may restore missing templates.

Comment: how to run this command(I'm new to visual studio)

Comment: I found that this command isn't for express. Anyway I ran the souitalbe command but it doesn't help. Maybe someone can upload the template file from his/her installation.

Comment: Fully demonstrative program, multiple resx files, including documentation and source code here https://tcimultilanguage.codeplex.com/

Comment: I found an easy way. Just needed to ctrl-c(copy) on the Resources.resx file and ctrl-v(paste) to make a copy of it and then I renamed.

Comment: The thing is, if you right click on your project and try to create new item, you can't see resx file (only resw). 
But if you go to File > New > File, you can create a resx file. I don't know why it's not available from the other part of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add separate resource file (.resx) for each language and use them by changing the thread UI Culture - http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/localizing-a-wpf-program-using-csharp.aspx.

See following screen-shot. Right-click on project -> Add -> New Item. Name your file according the culture you want. I named it for Dutch language.

[image]

Comment: Again, how to create the resx files? I have no option to create them. Also there' s no Properties folder in project's directory. There is a resources.resx file in project's directory(if I go there via windows explorer), which appears as a folder on solution explorer.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I haven't this entry. I will post a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You can do a similar thing if you go to your Project's Properties, and then go to the "Resources" tab there.

Multiple ways to get to Project Properties:

1. MENU: Project > Properties
2. Solution Explorer: Expand the project so the "Properties" node is visible. Double-click on it.

Another way (if you really want to add a file) is to right-click on your project (Solution Explorer) and click Add New Item. Here, on the left-hand side select "General" and on the right-hand side select "Resources File".

Comment: Yes I know that, but how to add translations with only one file? Also there is no option in General to add a resx file. Only options is config file, manifest file and empty text file