# Changing ressources files language in development

Tags: c#

How to change ressources files from one language to another language resources having at his disposal the file Properties.resources.resx?

Comment: what kind of application you are developing?

Comment: @Joseph: I believe Momar is dealing with a C# desktop application, [this one](https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync) more precisely.

Comment: You should provide more informations to help up helping you.

Comment: This is an application Desktop C #. I have got the resources files for the English language and I want to translate it into another language.
But when I replace Properties.resources.resx file in english by Properties.resources.resx in another language, the result remains the same as before remains in English.

Comment: Am I right you want to provide multiple languages for your application?

Comment: So you need a resource file for each language. For example Resources.{lang}.resx.

Comment: What language do you want to add?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul i want to add Wolof language, a language spoken in Senegal.
I added this feature (translation in Wolof) in a final project cycle.
I already translated all words.

Comment: Does the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217485/how-to-add-resx-file-in-visual-studio-express-2012 work?

Comment: It doesn't work because i can't change **"System.Globalization.CultureInfo"**.